# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: windows, stack-overflow

I am using Janus(Third Party) Grid and getting the "System.StackOverflowException". Don't know how to solve it. I would like to appreciate for any help.

```
     private void gridEX1_FormattingRow(object sender, RowLoadEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.Row.RowIndex;
        try
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(gridEX1.GetRow(index).Cells["HEADER_ORDER_PACKAGE_ROW_ID"].Value))
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(gridEX1.GetRow(index).Cells["HEADER_ORDER_PACKAGE_ROW_ID"].Value) == PARENT_ORDER_PACKAGE_ID)
                {

                    **gridEX1.MoveToRowIndex(index);**
                    GridEXRow curRow = gridEX1.GetRow();
                    if (curRow != null)
                    {
                        curRow.Expanded = true;

                    }

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably one of `gridEX1` methods called from `gridEX1_FormattingRow` raises `FormattingRow` event, which causes endless recursion. Debug this to see whether this is the case. The simple way to solve this is to unsubscribe from `FormattingRow` event in the beginning of `gridEX1_FormattingRow` method and to subscribe again in the end. Maybe your application logic may require more flexible solution.

Comment: BTW, `catch (Exception ex)` without any reaction effectively hides your own bugs - well-known `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` way to have undefined behavior. Don't write code like VB6 programmer...

Comment: I am not able to "Catch" the exception as it is stop on   **gridEX1.MoveToRowIndex(index);**  line ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of the lines inside your handler invoke the handler itself again. And so on, so you get StackOverflow.

Comment: I am not able to "Catch" the exception as it is stop on gridEX1.MoveToRowIndex(index); line.

Comment: Of course you can't. You can't catch StackOverflow because of CLR policy. And you should never catch StackOverflow. You should somehow avoid this exception. You have to avoid reformatting of your grid from within the handler.